# Is there any way to dynamically set multiple VALUES in mysql 'insert' query in nodejs?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am working on nodejs for the first time. I have a scenario where I am having json array like shown below.
I will not know how many json items will be there in that array.

I have tried solution using loops but it will fire the query for multiple times. And I don't want that.

```
{"qualification":[{"degreeName":"B","domain":"p"},{"degreeName":"A","domain":"q"}]}
```

And mysql query will be like this

```sql
INSERT INTO qualification (degreeName,domain) VALUES (B,p),(A,q);
```

In the above query I have explicitly written values, but as I will not know how many values will be there I can't write values like that, instead i will have to put all values in a variable and then pass it to the query.
So how can I retrive and convert qualification data into varible or tuples to put into mysql query so that I can fire single query and add multiple values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this: You'll have to generate `values` array from dynamic values and pass onto the query.

> Key point: `?` is a unnamed parameter (placeholder alias) to make it **Parameterised Query**

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "yourusername",
  password: "yourpassword",
  database: "mydb"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
  let sql = "INSERT INTO qualification (degreeName, domain) VALUES ?";
  let values = [
    ['B', 'p'],
    ['A', 'q'],
    ...
  ]; //this is dynamic value that you can create
  con.query(sql, [values], function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Number of records inserted: " + result.affectedRows);
  });
});
```

To generate the tuples (`values`) from the dataset (assumes that data is going be in that format):

```
const payload = {
  qualification: [
    { degreeName: "B", domain: "p" },
    { degreeName: "A", domain: "q" }
  ]
};
const tuples = payload.qualification.map(obj => [obj.degreeName, obj.domain]);
```

Which OPs something like this:

```
[ [ 'B', 'p' ], [ 'A', 'q' ] ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. You exactly got what I wanted to say.

Comment: @SwapnilNakade Great. Happy to help! if the solution resolved you issue please mark it as accepted.